# Using a regular expression to extract URLs from links in an HTML document

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need to capture all links in a given html.

Here is sample code:

```
<div class="infobar">
    ... some code goes here ...
    <a href="/link/some-text">link 1</a>
    <a href="/link/another-text">link 2</a>
    <a href="/link/blabla">link 3</a>
    <a href="/link/whassup">link 4</a>
    ... some code goes here ...
</div>
```

I need to get all links inside `div.infobar` that starts with `/link/`

I tried this:

```
preg_match_all('#<div class="infobar">.*?(href="/link/(.*?)") .*?</div>#is', $raw, $x);
```

but it gives me the only first match.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Maybe there's an html parser that will do this more easily for you?

Comment: I am already getting it first getting the inside of div.infobar with preg_match then getting the links with preg_match_all. but since regex offers more flexibility, why I shouldn't use it? I just need a good pattern. I want to know how to accomplish that with just 1 preg_match_all

Comment: You cannot do that with a single regex. You first need to isolate the div and then extract the desired links from it. -- What the stubby comments are about: you can extract the links easier with phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) using `foreach (qp($html)->find("div.infobar a") as $a) { print $a->attr("href"); }` Using a specific regex is really only appropriate for performance reasons, if it's a known coherent html input blob.

Comment: HTML is not a regular language, so it is [unwise to use a regular expression to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @stereofrog, fair point; there's no way I can improve upon [anubhava's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461732/using-a-regular-expression-to-extract-urls-from-links-in-an-html-document/6461935#6461935) for this specific case, and I think a little levity is a fantastic way to show that trying to use the wrong tool for the job can lead to incredible frustration.

Comment: @Stereofrog, [our very own Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) provides further advice that parsing a non-regular language such as HTML with a regular expression might just work most of the time, but is brittle. Yes, [newer engines called 'regular expression'](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) can match some non-regular languages, but I still believe a match written in one of these languages will be harder to maintain over time than using a more powerful parser such as the `DOMDocument` or XPath approaches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this very purpose rather than using regex. Consider following simple code:

```
$content = '
<div class="infobar">
    <a href="/link/some-text">link 1</a>
    <a href="/link/another-text">link 2</a>
    <a href="/link/blabla">link 3</a>
    <a href="/link/whassup">link 4</a>
</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

// To hold all your links...
$links = array();

// Get all divs
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div");
foreach($divs as $div) {
  // Check the class attr of each div
  $cl = $div->getAttribute("class");
  if ($cl == "infobar") {
    // Find all hrefs and append it to our $links array
    $hrefs = $div->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach ($hrefs as $href)
       $links[] = $href->getAttribute("href");
  }
}
var_dump($links);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "/link/some-text"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "/link/another-text"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "/link/blabla"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "/link/whassup"
}
```

Comment: Lets see if the op still thinks regex are better :d

Comment: what is the execution time between this and regex? I can do this with just 2 preg_match_all functions.

Comment: Execution time will be comparable (or even better) than regex based code but more importantly DOM based code will NOT break at unexpected time as compared to regex code.

Answer (score 2):

Revising my previous answer. You'll need to do it in two steps:

```
//This first step grabs the contents of the div.
preg_match('#(?<=<div class="infobar">).*?(?=</div>)#is', $raw, $x);

//And here, we grab all of the links.
preg_match_all('#href="/link/(.*?)"#is', $x[0], $x);
```

Comment: Thanks. but this time it gets the last one :D

Comment: I split it into two steps. The div gets matched the first time, and then can't be matched again.

Answer (score 2):

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ :

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I added a `+`):

```
preg_match_all('#<div class="infobar">.*?(href="/link/(?:.*?)")+ .*?</div>#is', $raw, $x);
```